# Multiple conditions in While loop JS

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, modulo

I don't really see how this could be wrong code.
In few examples, there is no output at all or it's only "10" in this one.

```
var num2 = 10;
while (num2 >= 10 && num2 <= 40 && num2%2===0){
    console.log(num2);
    num2++;
}
```

or like this:

```
var num2 = 10;
while (num2 >= 10 && num2 <= 40){
    if (num2%2===0){
    console.log(num2);
    num2++;
}}
```

Comment: What do you expect from this code? Try executing it step by step in a debugger

Comment: To print even numbers between 10 and 40

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first loop stops after the first iteration because `11` is not an even number, so `num2%2===0` is `false`.

Your second loop never stops because it only increments `num2` if it's even (from `10` to `11`), but `11` is not even and so `num2` never changes.

Fix:

```js
var num2 = 10;
while (num2 >= 10 && num2 <= 40) {
    if (num2%2===0) {
        console.log(num2);
    }
    num2++;
}
```

I.e. always increment `num2`, but only print the even numbers.

Alternatively:

```js
var num2 = 10;
while (num2 >= 10 && num2 <= 40) {
    console.log(num2);
    num2 += 2;
}
```

I.e. start at an even number and always increment by 2.

Comment: God, these devil curly brackets in wrong places :D Thanks